# compiling library for arm architecture

Tags: linux, cross-platform, arm, cross-compiling

I want to know how i can cross compile a library for ARM architecture. Suppose i have libcurl library for Intel architecture and now i want to run the application in ARM architecture using this library. What are the steps i need to perform for this cross compilation. I am using Ubuntu 32-bit machine.
I have gone through the basic steps like

```
./configure --host= ...
make 
make install
```

but could not get the complete idea. Please provide some useful link or if anybody can explain the things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know there is a post in SO for this already "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832734/cross-compiling-a-library-from-intel-to-arm" , but i did not get the things clarified by this.

Platform : linux , gcc compiler

Comment: make install? Check: you are aware this does not make your arm binary run on intel?

Comment: You probably want to add DESTDIR to make install. http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to give toolchain for your architecture the host parameter, for example for [arm-1808](http://www.ti.com/product/am1808) which basically has an arm architecture, the host parameter would be arm-none-linux. I used the following configure command for my architecture, and it compiled successfully, and I am able to run the application on my arm board.

**0.**

If tool chain is not in your PATH, then you can include it with a command like this:

```
 export PATH=/home/user/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin/:$PATH
```

**1.**

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux CFLAGS='-Os' --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --enable-smtp
```

**2.**

```
make
```

**3.**

```
sudo make install
```

**4.** Now its time to build your application.

```
  arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o email smtp-multi.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl
```

Basically you need to give CPP and CF flags while compiling your application, to find out the CF and CPP flags you can use the following commands respectively:

```
curl-config --cflags  

curl-config --libs
```

If above commands do not work then try:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o email smtp-multi.c -lcurl
```